# Node.js res.send is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm trying the following code but it's giving me an error, "res.send is not a function". Please help me.

Here's the code:

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
var connect = require('connect');
var express = require('express');

var app = express();
app.get('/', function(res, req  ) {
        res.send('Hello World');
    });

var server = app.listen(8888, function(){
    var host = server.address().address;
    var port = server.address().port;
    console.log("Example app listening at http://%s:%s", host, port);
});
```

The server is running fine and is connecting. The complete error that is being displayed is something like this:

> TypeError: res.send is not a function
>       at c:\wamp\www\node\server.js:8:13
>       at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (c:\wamp\www\node\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
>       at next (c:\wamp\www\node\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
>       at Route.dispatch (c:\wamp\www\node\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
>       at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (c:\wamp\www\node\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
>       at c:\wamp\www\node\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
>       at Function.process_params (c:\wamp\www\node\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
>       at next (c:\wamp\www\node\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
>       at expressInit (c:\wamp\www\node\node_modules\express\lib\middleware\init.js:40:5)
>       at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (c:\wamp\www\node\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)

Answer (score 100, accepted):

According to the [API reference](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html), the first param always contain request `req`, then response `res`.

So change first param `res` to `req`:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.send("Rendering file")
}
```

It should fix it.

Comment: this helped me as well. just swapping the `res` and `req`. thanks

Answer (score 27):

You've got the `res` and `req` parameters the wrong way around.

```js
app.get('/', function(res, req)
```

should be

```js
app.get('/', function(req, res)
```

Source: [API docs](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app.get.method).

Answer (score 6):

Swap req & res : `function(req, res)`

Answer (score 3):

Everything fine. Good Work. Just make a little change in parameters e.g (req, res) instead of (res, req). Its a Rule.

Answer (score 0):

you should use req argument first and res as the second argument this will work without any issue

```js
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
 res.send("Rendering file")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change your mind in some cases and could be write like this.
*note: by default, when you run node server on your local machine. Your host will always be localhost:"your desire port"*
Thank you!

```
const express = require("express")
const app = express();
const port = 8888;
// for redering hello you don't need to require fs
const fs = require("fs")

app.get ('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send("hello world")
})


app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on ${port}`))
```

Answer (score 0):

The middleware function you are writing is a callback function and should follow the order of declaring params `function(req, res, next)` `req` for request `res` for response and `next` for further operation. You can refer to [API reference](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html).

So the proper code would be:

```
var express = require('express');
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
var connect = require('connect');

var app = express();
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
        res.send('Hello World');
    });

var server = app.listen(8888, function(){
    var host = server.address().address;
    var port = server.address().port;
    console.log("Example app listening at http://%s:%s", host, port);
});
```