# TypeError: res.Send is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have this function:

```
app.get('/counter', function (req, res) {

    console.log('/counter Request');
    var counter = 0;
    fs.readFile(COUNTER_FILE_NAME, function(err, data) {
        counter = data;
    });
    console.log('Read Counter: ' +  counter);
    counter = counter + 1;

    // delete old file
    fs.unlink(COUNTER_FILE_NAME, function (err) {
        if (err) console.log('Cant chagne old counter file');
    });

    fs.appendFile(COUNTER_FILE_NAME, counter, function (err) {
        if (err) if (err) console.log('Cant create new counter file');
    });

    console.log('Change Counter To: ' + counter);
    res.status(200);
    res.writeHead('content-type','text/plain')
    res.Send(counter);
})
```

for unknown reason I'm getting the following error:

```
TypeError: res.Send is not a function
```

I looked at this post:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44176021/nodejs-res-send-is-not-a-function](http://NodeJS%20res.send%20is%20not%20a%20function)

and it's looks like other bug.

How can I fix it ?

Comment: There are other things wrong with this code.  You need to wait until `fs.readFile()` is done before proceeding to use the `counter` value.  You need to wait until `fs.unlink()` is done before calling `fs.appendFile()` and you are sending your response before either is done.  This code shows a complete lack of understanding of asynchronous operations in node.js and it will not work properly.  Also unclear is `counter` in your file is a string in which case `counter + 1` will likely not do what you want.

Comment: @jfriend00 is correct, the TypeError is the least of your worries.   Your `readFile`, `unlink`, `appendFile`, are all going to get executed pretty much in parallel.  Welcome to the world of async programming.

Comment: Also, what is this: `if (err) if (err) `?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TYPO

`res.Send(counter);` => `res.send(counter);`

https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.send

Comment: There are also a whole bunch of other things wrong with this code.  This may prevent interpreter exceptions, but multiple other things must be fixed before this code will actually work.